# check out a "pull request" on Git to review/test a PR

Tags: git, github, git-pull, pull-request

We have a repo that I have added to my local fork as Upstream. Someone sent a PR and I want to review it. Although I'm able to review code on Github by their Diff tool but I want to have it on my local machine and test it on a real device in order to make sure it works fine (Android repo it is).

What is best way to checkout this PR?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's somewhat underdocumented, but GitHub provides pull requests as branches on your Upstream repository so you don't need to add remotes for each third party who might send you a pull request.

So

```
git fetch Upstream pull/1044/head:pr1044-from-someone
```

will make the commits in the pull request available in your local repository in a new branch, *pr1044-from-someone*, which you can review and merge locally as appropriate.

See [help.github.com's Modifying an inactive pull request locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally) for more details.

Comment: The most simple one. Thanks John.

Comment: The upstream repository is conventionally called `origin`, so this lends itself to a convenient alias (taking the PR number and optionally a new branch name): `git config --global alias.prfetch '!f() { git fetch origin pull/$1/head${2:+:$2}; }; f'`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

- add the PR's repository as a remote in your local copy

  ```
  git remote add remote_name github.com/user/proj
  ```
- fetch changes from this remote

  ```
  git fetch remote_name branch_name_to_fetch
  ```
- checkout the changes using

  ```
  git checkout remote_name/branch_name_to_fetch
  ```

And now you can test it as per your needs on your local, you can create new branch, take a diff between branches, and so on.

PS: IMO, this is slightly tedious compared to your current approach - if you get a lot of pull requests, adding all the remotes can be confusing and fetching all the branch history is sub-optimal, a patch is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out how to do that. Let me explain what I did for everyone how has same question.

1. Goto PR page on Github. The URL should looks like `https://github.com/YOUR-NAME/REPO-NAME/pull/1044/files`
2. Add `.patch` at the end of URL and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> so the URL looks like `https://github.com/YOUR-NAME/REPO-NAME/pull/1044/files.patch`
3. Download this file or if is not downloadable create a text file, copy page and paste it into text file. Make sure the extension file is `.patch` (not `.txt`)
4. Create a new local branch and checkout into that branch
5. Take a look at what changes are in the patch by following command. This is just stat and doesn't apply anything: `git apply --stat fix_empty_poster.patch`
6. By following command you will see how close to trouble you are :) If there is no complain be happy: `git apply --check fix_empty_poster.patch`
7. Finally you can patch it by following command: `git am --signoff < fix_empty_poster.patch`

Now, you have a copy of branch for review.

More references:

1. [GitHub Tip: download commits as patches](http://chem-bla-ics.blogspot.com/2011/01/github-tip-download-commits-as-patches.html)
2. [How to create and apply a patch with Git](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/)

Comment: This worked for me, just a correction adding .patch on /files doesn't work but it worked as https://github.com/YOUR-NAME/REPO-NAME/pull/1044.patch